# Apply mask array on another array in KQL

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, kusto-explorer

I have created a function which accepts two arrays (both containing numbers). I need the function to output first array, but whenever 2nd array contains 0, replace value in 1st array with null.

```
let replace_with_nulls = (src:dynamic, mask:dynamic)
{
  src[i] = mask[i]==0 ? null : src[i]
};
```

It seems I should probably use mv-apply function, but the documentation is utmost confusing.

EDIT:
The function that I'm looking needs to return a result which can be used in a table. Something like this:

```
let replace_with_nulls = (src:dynamic, mask:dynamic)
{
let table= union (print src_col=src, mask_col=mask);
table
| mv-expand src_col,mask_col 
| extend res_col = iif(mask_col==0, int(null), src_col)
| summarize result= series_fill_forward(make_list_with_nulls(res_col))
};
datatable (src:dynamic, mask:dynamic)[
dynamic([1, 2, 3, 4,5]),dynamic([0, 1, 0, 1,0])
]
|extend tgt = replace_with_nulls(src, mask);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function to achieve your requirement.

```
let replace_with_nulls = (src:dynamic, mask:dynamic)
{
let table= union (print src_col=src, mask_col=mask);
table
| mv-expand src_col,mask_col 
| extend res_col = iif(mask_col==0, int(null), src_col)
| summarize result= make_list_with_nulls(res_col)
};
```

The function works by first creating a Kusto table with two columns (`src_col` and `mask_col`) using the union operator and the print plugin. Then, it uses mv-expand to expand the table into individual rows, and res_col is computed from src_col with`iif` function to replace the values in src_col with null wherever the corresponding value in mask_col is 0. Finally, it uses summarize make_list_with_nulls to create a new dynamic array that contains all the values in the res_col column.

When the above function is called,the result is as below,

**calling UDF:**

```
let src = dynamic([1, 2, 3, 4,5]);
let mask = dynamic([0, 1, 0, 1,0]);
replace_with_nulls(src, mask);
```

**Result:**

| result |
| --- |
| [null,2,null,4,null] |

Comment: Your example works well, unfortunately I'm likely facing another issue as this function returns tabular result, while I need (probably) my function to return scalar result and that throwing another error. I'll edit my initial question to add more context

Comment: 1) `mv-expand` is tabular operator, we cannot use this for scalar values. So, Tabular function is used instead of scalar function.
2) If we convert the result of this function to scalar using `toscalar`, then when calling the function, we will get the error ` 'toscalar': can't use 'src_col' as it is defined outside its row-context scope. Refer the [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction#limitations) on `toscalar_limitations`.

Comment: 3) The only way to achieve this is using the extend operator inside the function itself and invoking the function outside. Refer the similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76941778/base-36-to-base-10-conversion-in-adx-kql/76958772)

Answer (score -1):

KQL does not accept direct modifications on arrays this way. `mv_apply` is a good function to make some modifications on these. Here's the code :

```
let replace_with_nulls = (src: dynamic, mask: dynamic) {
    mv-apply if (mask == 0) then null else toscalar(src) on i
};
```

This line uses `mv-apply` to modify arrays, then it compares the value of the mask at current index.
If `mask = 0` it will replace in array 2 the value of 0 by null and then with the help of toscalar it will assign the value of `mask(i)` to `src(i)` which will become null.

Remember that `toscalar()` can't be applied on a scenario that applies the function on each row